# How to get product collection based on custom price attribute in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, product, price, product-collection

I am using Magento 2.2.2

I have created one attribute "Retail Price". Input type for this attribute is "Price". I have added values in some products for this attribute. Now I want to load product collection based on "Retail Price" range. I have tried using the following code:

```
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->addAttributeToFilter('retail_price' , array('from' => 501, 'to' => 700));
$collection->load();
```

After using the above code I didn't get any products in the result. So, what can be the issue in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

**Try This :-**

```
$collection = $productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1)
                ->addFieldToFilter('retail_price', array('gteq' => 501))
                ->addFieldToFilter('retail_price', array('lteq' => 700));
```

Comment: I have implemented your solution but it's not working. Is there any alternate solution for this?

Comment: any error ?????

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: how can I apply greater or equal(>=)/ less or equal(<=) instead of only 'gt' and 'lt'?

Comment: check my updated answer

Comment: "gteq" for greater or equal and "lteq" for  less or equa